# Combine 2 rain-drop effect ICs

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transistors, current, resistors

[image]

The image is from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETHB7nzrTWk&t=301s&ab_channel=ElectronicsProjectsStefano91ste).

This circuit is to produce a beautiful rain drop effect as shown in the link.

Is it possible that we can extend the rain LED to 20 LEDs instead of just 10 LEDs as shown in the diagram? Basically, all 20 LEDs will produce a rain drop, lighting one after one consecutively.  Can we combine two CD4017 ICs to make 20 pins? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Cmos device 4017 is a decoded output counter, you cannot chain them or at least the result would not be the wanted one. The wanted one effect could be got by chaining if there was used some  on a shift register based design. But this one is not such. You can get the expansion easiest by having one 4017 + 2 sets of leds which get in turns the GND and the sets are swapped every time when the counter starts from the first output. Needs some design, of course. And a flipflop to make the swap.

Comment: Using a 74hct595 would be "cascadable" ...

Comment: Shouldn't a rain-drop be seen to accelerate as it falls?

Comment: @Andyaka That could probably be done (repeatedly) with that circuit by protecting it with foam and dropping it ;)

Comment: ... Or more sensibly by appropriate spacing of the LEDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to daisy chain 4017's, the schematic is in the datasheet:

[image: Example of cascading 4017 ICs]

Image source: [Texas Instruments (originally Harris Semiconductor) CD4017B datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf)

It is a bit cumbersome, because you lose 2 outputs per chips.

How it works: when output 9 is tied to /CE, and the counter enables this output, it sets /CE to 1 which inhibits the clock and freezes the counter. The AND gates then propagate the clock to the next chip. The last chip resets the first when it reaches Q9.

If you just want to make a LED cascade with lots of LEDs, I guess you could multiplex them and use just 2x CD4017, one for the rows and one for the colums.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a single 4017 and a few transistors. I have changed the 555 to a TLC555 to get close to 50% duty cycle.

Say the 4017 has just been clocked to OUTPUT 0 high (meaning the clock input is high). Q3 will conduct and turn on D1. Then the 555 output goes low then Q2 turns on, Q3 turns off, and D2 turns on, all others are off. On the next positive edge of the 555 output the 4017 advances to OUT 1, so D3 illuminates.. and so on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEskBD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>